# Regex - match mathematical expressions inside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that will match valid math expressions inside of a pair of parentheses that **do not contain any parenthesis of their own**.

- The input is pre-validated, and only contains valid mathematical expressions.

For example, given the following input, the regex should match `3*4.5`:

> (1 + 2 + 3 + 5 * 9 + 2 + 3 + (3*4.5))

I wrote the following regular expression which matches the simple case of up to one mathematical operation inside parentheses:

```
(?:-?\()(-?\d*\.*\d*\s*[-\+\*/]?\s*-?\d*\.*\d*)(?:\))
```

It successfully matches `3*4.5`.

However, since the number of mathematical operations is unknown, I need the solution to be more generic. Naively, I thought this would work (added the `+` after the capture group):

```
 (?:-?\()((-?\d*\.*\d*\s*[-\+\*/]?\s*-?\d*\.*\d*)+)(?:\))
```

However, the result is a timeout. See [here](http://regexr.com/3b3es).

The desired regex should return **3 * 4.5 + 7 /3 * -2** for the input below

> (1 + 2 + 3 + 5 * 9 + 2 + 3 + (3 * 4.5 + 7 /3 * -2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a regex that will match `(` then any character other than `)` and `(` and then `)`:

```
\(([^()]+)\)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ6vY7/3). The result is captured into Group 1.

Or, if you have an unfiltered input (i.e. it can contain string like `(The dog barks at midnight.&@$:*{^{%{#]£¥28/9")`, we can restrict this to forbid any letters inside with `\(([^a-zA-Z()]+)\)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ6vY7/4)).

```js
var re = /\(([^()]+)\)/g; 
var str = '(1 + 2 + 3 + 5 * 9 + 2 + 3 + (3 * 4.5 + 7 /3 * -2))\n(1 + 2 + 3 + 5 * 9 + 2 + 3 + (3*4.5))';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
  }
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: This also matches `(The dog barks at midnight.&@$:*{^{%{#]£¥28/9")`. That seems incompatible with OP's requirement to match "valid math expressions inside of a parenthesis."

Comment: I think the input is already "filtered". At least nothing is mentioned about that in the question. Surely the regex can be refined by forbidding letters, like `\(([^a-zA-Z()]+)\)`.

Comment: you may be right; I'm just throwing this out there. Maybe OP can clarify.

Comment: yes, the input is pre-validated. I added it to my question for others.